# ASP.NET Core Virtual directory in IIS Express

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, web-config, asp.net-core, iis-express

i created two aspnet core web and api projects under one solution using VS2015

```
src
|
|-app.web
|  |-localhost:29999/
|  |-startup.cs 
|  
|-app.api
   |-localhost:29999/api/
   |-startup.cs (app.Map("/api", api => { /*configs and route*/ });)
```

and modified `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` file like below to use virtual directory

```
<site name="ThreeCON.Web" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\proj\src\app.web\wwwroot" />
      <virtualDirectory path="/api" physicalPath="C:\proj\src\app.api\wwwroot" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:29999:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

when i try to access the url `localhost:29999/api` **while debugging**, i'm getting `404 not found` error (where `localhost:29999/` is working fine)

But when i deploy the same to dev server by creating virtual directory in IIS, **its working fine**. so how can i fix this to work with **IIS Express**

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that the virtual directory is not being recognised as it is Kestrel that is handling this and not actually IIS Express. Basically, Kestrel doesn't know that the Virtual Directory exists, so it cannot serve it up as such.

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030121/virtual-directory-inside-of-asp-net-core-app-in-iis?answertab=active#47433731), and subsequent blog post link provided in the answer led me to this conclusion and to solve this issue that I too encountered.