# Can not access virtual directory under virtual dotnet core api application on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-8, virtual-directory

I am trying to add a virtual directory to my dotnet core API. But it gives me a 404.

```
This api.project.nl page can’t be found

No web page was found for the web address: 

https://api.project.nl/v1/uploads/profiles/profile.jpeg
```

I have set up my api as `v1` under the main IIS website as you can see in my IIS project configuration below. The api works fine and I can even reach the `/docs` folder in my `wwwroot` whichs serves a `index.html` (for the custom swagger ui docs).

[image]

I **can** reach the `uploads` folder under the the `Projects - Api` folder

```
https://api.project.nl/uploads/profiles/profile.jpeg
```

but it **cannot** reach the `uploads` folder under the `v1` virtual application.

```
https://api.project.nl/v1/uploads/profiles/profile.jpeg
```

Any idea why? Am I not sure if its possible at all, would appreciate some pointers on this. I have seen some related questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030121/virtual-directory-inside-of-asp-net-core-app-in-iis) but my configuration is just a step futher. They talk about `UseFileServer` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) and they got it to work with that, but I can not seem to get it working it all. Not really sure I need that though.

Not sure if needed but here is my `StartUp.cs`

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Project Web Api Docs",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact { Name = "-", Email = "-", Url = "https://project.nl" }
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            // add policy for a global '[Authorize]' attribute filter,
            // so it doesn't have to be placed on all controllers
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();

            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        // Configure rollbar error reporting
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddRollbarWeb(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

        // inject an implementation of ISwaggerProvider with defaulted settings applied           
        services.AddSwaggerGen();

        services.AddOptions();

        // Inject the api settings
        services.Configure<ApiSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApiSettings"));

        // Configure mappings
        Mappings.ConfigureMappings();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        // Configure CORS settings
        app.UseCors(builder =>
           builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000", "http://localhost:8100", "https://connect.project.nl")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials()
           );

        // Configure rollbar
        app.UseRollbarExceptionHandler();

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Audience = Configuration["ApiSettings:Auth0:ClientId"],
            Authority = $"https://{Configuration["ApiSettings:Auth0:Domain"]}/"
        });

        app.UseMvc();

        // enable static files, for the wwwroot (and accompanying docs in it)
        // also enable 'default files', such as default.htm, index.html etc.
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
        app.UseSwagger(routeTemplate: "docs/{apiVersion}/swagger.json");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's because when you run an ASP.NET Core application in IIS, IIS acts only as reverse proxy and will redirect all requests to Kestrel and kestrel is unaware of virtual folders. ASP.NET Core applications aren't handle by the HttpPlatformHandler anymore but by ASPNetCoreHandler which is a fork of HttpPlatformHandler

Comment: Thanks for you comment, it made things a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am agree with @Tseng but I will add following thing .

1. ASP.net core is build for multi plateform so it does not handle some request or manage Virtual Directory or Application like IIS in other OS as well.
   In your case V1 is application in your main application
2. If you have to do any such thing then you have do following thing.

   ```
   app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
       {
           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(<<your physical path>>),
           RequestPath = new PathString("/V1"),
           EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true // you make this true or false.
       });
   ```

Once you do this configuration you don't need to configure in IIS.

Comment: Thanks, made things much clearer. used your approuch