# How can I get the physical path from a virtual path in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET, I have used the `Server.MapPath()` method to get the physical path. Now in core, I can't do that, I have used `IHostingEnvironment`, but it can only get `wwwroot` path.

Comment: I look some article ,this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562149/can-not-access-virtual-directory-under-virtual-dotnet-core-api-application-on-ii) make me know how to solve the quesion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380851/7149454

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers)

```
var contents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("");
return contents.Select(i => i.PhysicalPath);
```

You can check out my [demo code](https://github.com/chuongxl/AspNetCoreSample)

Comment: I have already try,it's a get file list from a directory ,Not to get physic path

Comment: you can get the physical path by its property = PhysicalPath

contents.Select(i => i.PhysicalPath); => it returns the physical path

Comment: I publish a website in IIS,and set a directory to virtual directory.Now I want to get the directory physic path to save file.

Comment: then what ? use "WebRootPath"?

Comment: inject IHostingEnvironment in your controller and then you can get your root path,


var rootPath =_env.ContentRootPath;

Comment: please use ContentRootPath or ContentRootFileProvider

Comment: i' sorry，it seem is not a good method.Now I write the physical path to appsetting to resolve this problem .Look forward to better method . How ever ,I'm  still thank you very much!