# What web.config setting will allow apple-app-site-association to be served?

Tags: iis, web-config, apple-app-site-associate

I have added the `apple-app-site-association` file to the root of a website, but IIS is not delivering the file.

What is the best way to make the server serve this specific file without a file extension? Is there a way within a web.config to explicitly say "serve this file"?

Comment: if you sorted this out, please let us know how.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found this amazing [post](https://medium.com/@barsh/my-first-date-with-ios-universal-links-90dfabc88bb8):

**Serving apple-app-site-association from IIS**
IIS only serves files of known types, defined by their file extension. Since apple-app-site-association doesn’t include a file extention, IIS throws a 404 error, when I try to open it with a browser. I fixed this by adding a mimeMap in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <!-- required for apple-app-site-association: -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**If the above solution does not work, then add the following rule**
Create a rule in the "web.config" file, which will provide the JSON value when the Applebot robot crawls your site for the apple association

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="apple_json_file">
                <match url="^apple-app-site-association" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="apple-app-site-association.json" />
            </rule>
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

Add this section in **system.webServer**

Comment: Better put this `system.webServer` node under a `<location path="apple-app-site-association">` node to restrict this only to this file and avoid serving any other extension less file.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957703/1178314), for security reasons, IIS only serves known file types, and uses the file extension to infer the file type. You can declare a file type for extension-less files, allowing to serve them.

But this causes the server to serve any extension-less file, which could cause unexpected files to get served to anyone, including robots probing for sensitive files incorrectly protected.

The solution explained by previously linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957703/1178314) can be restricted to only that apple file. Better restrict it. Use a `location` node for this.
By the way, consider adjusting the caching policy for this file, if your default one is not suitable, especially if your server is behind a CDN.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  ...

  <location path="apple-app-site-association">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="08:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

  ...

</configuration>
```

Comment: How would you go about this when the `apple-app-site-association` file is inside of the `.well-known` folder? I'm currently facing this issue, since I can't give up the path of `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` the dot here seems the IIS server to give an error

Comment: You can drop a web.config file in any folder you like. So just take the example above without the lines with three dots, put it in a web.config file inside the `.well-known` folder. This trouble already has its own [question and answer](/q/39365605/1178314).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I indeed got it to work with a web.config file in the .well-known directory. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Not my preferred solution, but in leu of DeyaEldeen's comment, the way I met many of our needs was to use the meta tag approach instead (within the `<head>` tag of the page):

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=5555555555">
```

This makes is so that whenever any users on iOS browse to the site, they are presented with a "view in app store" popup at the top of the page. Once they press on the popup, they get directed to the app store.

See [Apple's docs for Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

Hopefully this helps some people with similar needs.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the solutions provided by mogile_oli [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957703/6083631) and Frédéric [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67022954/6083631) a little more configuration is required when using IIS configured for a **Net.Core** site.

**TLDR: Remove `aspNetCore` handler in the `.well-known/web.config` and apply existing solution by either mogile_oli or Frédéric**

One solution is to place the .well-known folder in the wwwroot folder as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71560161/6083631). However this either means making the `apple-app-site-association` part of your .Net Core project or manually adding this after any publish update. You then make the MIME changes mentioned by mogile_oli or Frédéric

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47433731/6083631) is to configure static files within the .Net Core app's startup class then the folder/files can live outside of the .Net Core project. This has the downside that this would require a rebuild of the application if you want to make any directory changes.

The solution we opted for doesn't require the .Net Core app to have any knowledge of the .well-known folder.

1. If you don't have it already create a `.well-known` folder in the root of the IIS site folder.
2. Add your `apple-app-site-association` (and if you doing the equivalent for android your `assetlinks.json` file too).
3. Add a web.config file to the `.well-known' folder with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
            <!-- Only required for assetlinks.json if your IIS version doesn't already have .json defined -->
            <!-- <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /> -->
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <!-- Assumes that you have the handler in your root web.config called aspNetCore. Change to match your configuration -->
            <remove name="aspNetCore" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

4. This code snippet stops the .Net Core app handling the .well-known folder and then we are free to configure it as per the previous solution by mogile_oli. (As an added bonus if you are adding assetlinks.json and using an older IIS version you need to add a mimeMap for .json files as well).
5. (Optional) The code snippet above has applied to the entire .well-known folder and as mentioned by Frédéric this can pose a security risk (especially if we have other files in the .well-known folder). We can transform the above to make use of Frédéric's location recommendation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="apple-app-site-association">
        <system.webServer>
            <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
            </staticContent>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="aspNetCore" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <!-- Only required for assetlinks.json -->
    <location path="assetlinks.json">
        <system.webServer>
            <!-- Only required if your IIS version doesn't already have .json defined -->
            <!-- <staticContent>
                <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            </staticContent> -->
            <handlers>
                <remove name="aspNetCore" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation as it took us a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

## Why

For security reasons, IIS cannot allow browsing any file. Imaging, for example, `web.config`.

## How to

The quickest way is to add the file type to the known types by its extension:

```
Open IIS Manager -> Sites -> Your Web Site -> MIME TYPES -> Add...
    File name extension=.
    MIME type=application/json
-> OK
```

Now it works.

Comment: Works perfect indeed, good alternative for the web.config way (which was asked for).

Answer (score 0):

I think giving blanket setting for just one file is not good. I have used following approach.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

In that handler I check for specific file request and do rersponse.write the json content to be served.

so the server setting is not compromised.

```
if(Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith("/apple-app-site-association"))
        {
            Response.Write(File.ReadAllText("/apple-app-site-association"));
            Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 500 Internal server error was coming while hosting the virtual directory on iis server. It got fixed by using below configuration in web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```