# How to force read or display content of file 'apple-app-site-association' on IIS server ec2 Instance?

Tags: angular, iis, amazon-ec2, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have a web application in angular 8 deployed on **Amazon ec2 server** with **IIS** windows hosting. There is a parallel mobile app which requires deep linking to be connected with my web app.

Mobile team developers provide us documentation to embed universal links on Web app server [Documentation](https://gonative.io/docs/deep-linking).
For android it works perfectly by creating a **.well-known** folder and place **assetlinks.json** in that.
For IOS as per documentation **apple-app-site-association** file was placed in **.well-known** and root folder as well, But it fails by validator provided by apple on this link [Apple Validator] [image: Apple validator results](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool).
The file  **apple-app-site-association** is extension less which is the main cause of this issue.
Content of file is as follows.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "app-id",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I placed an extra file **apple-app-site-association.json** with main extension less file and then added below rule in web.config

```
      <rule name="apple_json_file">
                   <match url="^apple-app-site-association" />
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="apple-app-site-association.json" />
      </rule>
```

and allow **.json** file to be readable by server or bots.

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />`

I also tried a solution on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67022954/10064073%5C%5C) but didn't got any success.
I want **apple-app-site-association** file to be validated by apple [Apple Validator](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool).
Any one with solution please help.

Comment: Try to remove the file without extension from .well-known folder. Then verify again.

Comment: If you are using Angular SSR then try to place the same .well-known folder containing apple-app-site-association file in "server" folder as well.

Comment: If that "server" folder attempt doesn't work then try to put the ".well-known" folder in the root directory where your domain is pointing not inside "dist" folder.

Comment: No need to use re-write/redirect method. As Apple has clearly mentioned in the documentation.

"After you create the apple-app-site-association file, upload it to the root of your HTTPS web server or to the .well-known subdirectory. The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—      WITHOUT ANY REDIRECTS       —at https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association or https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association."

Comment: The apple-app-site-association file should not have any file extension,  this question and its answers may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370867/configure-apple-app-site-association-file-and-upload-on-server