# Server.MapPath with virtual directory on .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

How do you do the equivalent of Server.MapPath to find the path of a virtual directory with .Net Core?

Comment: The answer appears to be that you simply shouldn't add virtual directories in IIS but instead map them programmatically, as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030121/virtual-directory-inside-of-asp-net-core-app-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

`Path.Combine(Env.WebRootPath, "SomePath")` is the equivalent..

`Env.WebRootPath` where Env = environment, usually from the startup.cs

**edit**

what about this...

`ApplicationEnvironment env = new ApplicationEnvironment();`
`env.ApplicationBasePath;`

there is a big thread about this on the asp.net core mvc on GitHub not sure if this is what you are looking for or not.

Comment: That would find the path to a sub-folder, but it wouldn't find the path to a mapped virtual directory.

Comment: Same problem. That would not help to find the path to a mapped virtual directory.