# Host Asp.Net Core and Asp.Net MVC 5 Web API under one IIS website

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net core website (say https://www.somesite.com) where I need to host an asp.net web api (.net framework 4.6) in  https://www.somesite.com/api, but I keep getting HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure for the API and the asp.net core website works just fine. Please help how can I achieve this.

This has always worked before ASP.NET Core

Comment: Ensure that your .NET Framework 4.6 sub-application is assigned an ApplicationPool which has .NET CLR version as `v 4.0` and your .net core website is using a different Application Pool with .NET CLR version `No Managed Code`

Comment: it's exactly like that. The sub-application is using the IIS default app pool and I created a different app pool for asp.net core. I still get the error

Comment: Ok! Check the server eventviewer for detailed error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. the log said it was trying to run the web API using "dotnet somesite.dll", so I had to exclude "aspnetcore" handler in the API web.config file. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789683/5584692